# Why Swing component font Size changes by different windows operating System

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have developed a java swing application in netbeans 7.1.3 on my windows 8 Pro PC. I have set font to Meriyo UI, size 11 to all component. If i run application in my windows 8 Pc it shows same font as i set. but if i run application on other windows 7 which is japnese version OS, on that machine font size changes for some components from 11 to 12. please help me, why that font size changes from 11 to 12.

Comment: The size it self might not be changing but the way the font is rendered is, welcome to cross platform development and why we highly recommending using layout managers for UI development.  It's also possible that the font you've chosen isn't available or is unsupported on the platform and Java has defaulted to some other font, which, again, renders differently

Comment: You might like to supply a screen shot of the comparison between the two